# Directory naming using Process ID and Thread ID

Tags: java, multithreading, pid

I have an application with a few threads that manipulate data and save the output in different temporary files on a particular directory, in a Linux or a Windows machine. These files eventually need to be erased.

What I want to do is to be able to better separate the files, so I am thinking of doing this by Process ID and Thread ID. This will help the application save disk space because, upon termination of a thread, the whole directory with that thread's files can be erased and leave the rest of the application reuse the corresponding disk space.

Since the application runs on a single instance of the JVM, I assume it will have a single Process ID, which will be that of the JVM, right?

That being the case, the only way to discriminate among these files is to save them in a folder, the name of which will be related to the Thread ID.

Is this approach reasonable, or should I be doing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.io.File can [create](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) temporary files for you. As long as you keep a list of those files associated with each thread, you can delete them when the thread exits. You can also mark the files to [delete on exit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) in case a thread does not complete.

Comment: I know of these possibilities, but the application handles a lot of data, so it may run out of disk space well before a thread exits.

Comment: How does your program know when it no longer requires each temporary file? Why are you concerned about organizing them if storage seems to be the issue?

Comment: It does some processing on the file and then can dispose it. I just need to organize them in directories as I described, process them and then erase the entire directory.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to organize your temporary files by process and thread id. As long as you have a reference to them in your program (ideally a `java.io.File` instance), you can delete them very easily, regardless of how they're organized.

Comment: For a number of reasons, including the possibility that any of the applications (or the server) crashes and leaves data on the disk. These will need to be cleaned up later on.

Comment: What OS?  On unix-like systems, usually you open a temp file and then delete it immediately.  You still have an open file descriptor (readable/writable), but when you exit (including via a crash) it's gone since the reference count on the file descriptor is zero.  Useless if you have to pass a filename to other processes, though.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the JVM has one process ID, and all threads in that JVM will share the process id.  (It is possible for a JVM to use multiple processes, but AFAIK, no JVM does that.)

A JVM may very well re-use underlying OS threads for multiple Java threads, so there is no guaranteed correlation between a thread exiting in Java and anything similar happening at the OS level.

If you just need to cleanup stale files, sorting the files by their creation timestamp should do the job sufficiently?  No need to encode anything special at all in the temporary file names.

Note that PIDs and TIDs are neither guaranteed to be increasing, no guaranteed to be unique *across exits*.  The OS is free to recycle an ID.  (In practice the IDs have to wrap around before re-use, but on some machines that can happen after only 32k or 64k processes have been created.

Comment: Cannot cleanup based on time or any other "filesystem" attribute, because the files are thread-specific.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the simplest solution for this approach is really to extend Thread - never thought I'd see that day.

As P.T. already said Thread IDs are only unique as long as the thread is alive, they can and most certainly will be reused by the OS.

So instead of doing it this way, you use the Thread name that can be specified at construction and to make it simple, just write a small class:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private static long ID = 0;

    public MyThread(Runnable r) {
        super(r, getNextName());
    }

    private static synchronized String getNextName() {
         // We can get rid of synchronized with some AtomicLong and so on, 
         // doubt that's necessary though
        return "MyThread " + ID++;
    }

}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new MyThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Name: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

You have to overwrite all constructors you want to use and always use the `MyThread` class, but this way you can guarantee a unique mapping - well at least 2^64-1 (negative values are fine too after all) which should be more than enough.

**Though** I still don't think that's the best approach, possibly better to create some "job" class that contains all necessary information and can clean up its files as soon as it's no longer needed - that way you also can easily use ThreadPools and co where one thread will do more than one job. At the moment you have business logic in a thread - that doesn't strike me as especially good design.